# What's the most idiomatic way to pick a value from a slice based on a condition in Go?

Tags: go, slice

I've been doing a lot of loops to filter values and sometimes even converted slices to maps with convenient indexes to achieve this, but I feel it might not be the best way to do it in Go. So:

Considering the following boilerplate code, what's the most idiomatic way to find the first person named "Bob" on `people` slice? `found` should be a bool variables to determine if a person named "Bob" was found or not.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Age int
    Name string
}

var people=[]Person{{Age:18,Name:"Deb"},{Age:22,Name:"Bob"},{Age:35,Name:"Bob"}}

func main() {
    FirstBob, found := // how to pick first "Bob"?
    fmt.Println(FirstBob)
}
```

Being more general: What's the most idiomatic way to pick the first value from a slice that matches a certain condition?

Comment: A loop's the idiomatic way. Writing an answer with more detail.

Comment: Interesting debate on the topic of map filters: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/RKymTuSCHS0

Comment: @VonC that's exactly why this question came to mind, absence of map filters seemed weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Age  int
    Name string
}

var people = []Person{{Age: 18, Name: "Deb"}, {Age: 22, Name: "Bob"}, {Age: 35, Name: "Bob"}}

func findPerson(people []Person, name string) (Person, bool) {
    for _, p := range people {
        if p.Name == name {
            return p, true
        }
    }
    return Person{}, false
}

func main() {
    FirstBob, found := findPerson(people, "Bob")
    if found {
        fmt.Println(FirstBob)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{22 Bob}
```

If you want to return a pointer to the `Person` struct,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Age  int
    Name string
}

var people = []Person{{Age: 18, Name: "Deb"}, {Age: 22, Name: "Bob"}, {Age: 35, Name: "Bob"}}

func findPerson(people []Person, name string) (*Person, bool) {
    for i := range people {
        p := &people[i]
        if p.Name == name {
            return p, true
        }
    }
    return nil, false
}

func main() {
    FirstBob, found := findPerson(people, "Bob")
    if found {
        fmt.Println(*FirstBob)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{22 Bob}
```

Comment: Will it become inefficient with large data sets?

Comment: @marcioAlmada: Yes, so use other algorithms: [The Art of Computer Programming: Volume 3: Sorting and Searching (2nd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/The-Art-Computer-Programming-Searching/dp/0201896850). For example, a binary search.

Comment: @marcioAlmada -- if you need efficiency querying huge datasets lots of ways, you may want a database. If the worry about efficiency is just abstract at this point, maybe don't worry yet. And somewhere in between, if you need one or two in-memory indices, you can always build those with a `map` or other options out there.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way is to write out the loop--for example, Go team member (and former Python coder) Andrew Gerrand's closing talk at GopherCon 2014 mentions other functional-style list-processing shortcuts ("filter", "map", etc.) at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKGmK_Z1Zl0&t=23m40s

The standard justification is that not using those shortcuts yields more consistent code (developers can't make different choices about whether to use `map` or not), and it's explicit (it's held to be more obvious when you're doing nested loops or loops over enormous datasets if the loops are visible as a `for` block).

That said, 1) if you repeat *the same kind of search* lots of places you might as well factor it like in peterSO's answer, and 2) "idiomatic" is an ideal that not all code satisfies all the time; if you think it makes your code vastly easier to work with, nothing stops you from writing a type-specific shortcut (think: `type People []Person; func (p People) FirstMatchingIndex(predicate func(p *Person) bool) int {...}`). The standard [`strings.IndexFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#IndexFunc) is close to a "find (the index of) the first item satisfying a predicate" function, for example.